# ng-show on a dircetives controller value

Tags: angularjs

I am still learning angular and got this Problem:

Service Definition:

```
app.service('headService', function($window) {

    this.display = 0;

    return {
        setTitle: function (newTitle) { $window.document.title = newTitle; },
        setDisplay: function (value) { this.display = value;},
        getDisplay: function () {
            if(this.display===undefined){
                this.display = 1;
            }
            return this.display
        }
    };
})
```

Controller Definition:

```
app.controller('startController', function(headService) {

    headService.setTitle('by app 3');
    this.isVisible = function () {
        if(headService.getDisplay()===1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

directive implementation

```
app.directive("startDirective", function(headService) {

    return {
        restrict : "E",
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/start.html',
        controller: 'startController'
    };

});
```

Now I would like to Show if the method this.isVisible Returns true

```
<div layout="column" flex>
    <start-directive></start-directive>
    <content-directive></content-directive>
    <login-directive></login-directive>
</div>
```

which is included by

```
<body ng-controller="bodyController">

    <application-directive layout="row" flex></application-directive>

</body>
```

But I can't get it running. Any hint?

Comment: What is `headService`, and where did it come from?

Comment: you *appear* to be trying to use the Controller As syntax, since you are not injecting `$scope`, but your `ng-show` is looking for `isVisible` on `$scope`.  you might want to show more of the surrounding HTML, specifically where the `ng-controller` is declared, to clarify this a bit.

Comment: Controller is declared in the directive...   controller: 'startController'

Comment: where you are using that property

Comment: I'm deleting my answer as its no more relevant

Comment: Please provide a plunker...to help you properly